# How to check if user clicks on added or cancel button when user opens a pass

Tags: web-services, ios6, passbook

I created a pass and user can add it by clicking on link or app. When user open that pass, how to check if user clicks added or cancel ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer - you can't! There are no hooks, calls or events in the current framework that provide this information.

Longer answer - you can make some assumptions, depending on whether you're installing the pass via a link or an App.

Example 1 - you distribute a link to a script that creates a pass record in your database and sends a .pkpass bundle to a device.  The pass contains the `webServiceURL` and `authenticationToken` keys. If your web service subsequently receives a registration request for this pass, you know that the user clicked 'Add'.  If not, you assume they clicked 'Cancel'.

Example 2 - your App creates the pass and Passbook presents the user with the option to Add/Cancel.  Your App queries the device pass database to see if it contains a pass with the `serialNumber` and `passTypeIdentifier` of the pass you created - if yes, they clicked 'Add', if no then assume they clicked 'Cancel'.  If your pass has the `webServiceURL` and `authenticationToken` keys, you could also use the registration check from Example 1 since all passes will register with your web service.

Comment: So the pass will be registered by index.php by weServerURL ?

Comment: If you set everything up correctly, when you add a pass to your device, your webService will receive a request from the phone to something like `http://192.168.1.105:8888/passesWebserver/v1/devices/4ea1458fcbc48435b34e78cb2cf67f61/registrations/‌​pass.cam-mob.passbookpasstest/E5982H-I2` containing `{"pushToken":"77469d4968ceb035f9f7869339e95da6899d04214644a4cd8125c5edbbf2da1c"}`  The `deviceLibraryIdentifier` and `pushToken` are unique to each `passTypeIdentifier` and are regularly rotated - it is impossible to know what the URL will be beforehand, so you need an index.php with a rewrite rule.

Comment: and I don't have to add any data in table: devices, registration, pass_name ?

Comment: We can't tell you what to do with the data - but you need to think what happens beyond registration. E.g. you will need to use the device token to send a push, then when the iPhone/iPod receives the push, it will call `http://192.168.1.105:8888/passesWebserver/v1/devices/4ea1458fcbc48435b34e78cb2c‌​f67f61/registrations/pass.cam-mob.passbookpasstest` and your web service will need to deliver back a response of `{"serialNumbers",["E5982H-I2"],"lastUpdated":"<timestamp>"}`. Without using a database and building logic to service all these requests, it will be difficult to scale your service